# How can I bind to a Grid ColumnDefinition Width in C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a binding:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty 
   EntryWidthProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(EntryWidth),
   typeof(int),
   typeof(SingleEntryGrid), 150, BindingMode.TwoWay);
public int EntryWidth { 
   get => (int)GetValue(EntryWidthProperty); 
   set => SetValue(EntryWidthProperty, value); 
}
```

and this C# code:

```
var column3 = new ColumnDefinition()
{
   Width = new GridLength(???, GridUnitType.Absolute)
};
```

Note that GridLength is a structure:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.gridlength?view=xamarin-forms

[image]

Does anyone know how I can bind to the value marked with ???

For more explanation here's what I am trying to do:

[image]

I would like to be able to set the width of the input box frames. Here in this example they are all the same width.

Comment: Why not simply bind your grid column width to viewmodel?

Comment: Try to change typeof(int) to typeof(string) in your EntryWidthProperty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that. As you said, the [GridLength](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.gridlength?view=xamarin-forms) is a struct, but maybe more important than that is that the [Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.gridlength.value?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_GridLength_Value) that you are setting is simply a public property with a getter (it's not even a [BindableProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties)). This means that you can only set it via a method, which in this case happens to be the `GridLength` ctor itself. You can check the code of the GridLength [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/GridLength.cs#L20).

What you can do is one of 2 things - either leave all of the widths that you need to be `Auto`, or subclass the `Grid` class.

If you decide to go for the first approach, you won't have to write any additional code. According to the [Rows and columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid#rows-and-columns) docs:

> `Auto` – the row height or column width is autosized based on the cell contents (Auto in XAML).

On a first glance, this should do the work, since all widths will take the max of the children's widths (in this case it will be 150). Unfortunately, this adds some overhead to the `Grid`'s rendering and it is not small at any case. If you look a bit down in the docs, you will see in a red warning, that you should:

> Try to ensure that as few rows and columns as possible are set to `Auto` size. Each auto-sized row or column will cause the layout engine to perform additional layout calculations. Instead, use fixed size rows and columns if possible. Alternatively, set rows and columns to occupy a proportional amount of space with the GridUnitType.Star enumeration value.

This can also be seen again in [Optimize layout performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/performance#optimize-layout-performance), which I strongly suggest you to read, if you have not already.

That being said, you can go with the second approach. The idea behind it is to have a bindable property inside your new class and upon setting this property, you will update your `ColumnDefinition`'s `Width` property. Unfortunately, this has to be done "manually". Here is an example with your property (I have changed its type to `double` to be the same as the column's `Width` property):

```cs
public partial class MainPage
{
    private ColumnDefinition column3;
    
    public static readonly BindableProperty EntryWidthProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(EntryWidth), typeof(double),
        typeof(SingleEntryGrid), (double) 150, BindingMode.TwoWay);
    public double EntryWidth
    {
        get => (double) GetValue(EntryWidthProperty);
        set
        {
            SetValue(EntryWidthProperty, value);
            if (column3 != null)
            {
                column3.Width = value;
            }
        }
    }
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    
        var grid = new SingleEntryGrid
        {
            ColumnDefinitions = new ColumnDefinitionCollection()
        };
        // TODO: Other columns
        column3 = new ColumnDefinition
        {
            // The default value for EntryWidth
            Width = new GridLength(150, GridUnitType.Absolute)
        };
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column3);
        // The rest of your code
        
        Content = grid;
    }
}
```

As you can see in the code, the third column is being set initially to an `Absolute` width of 150 (the default value for your `EntryWidth`). After some change in the `EntryWidth` property's value, the setter will automatically change the third column.

Of course, this isn't the most elegant solution, since it is always updating only the third column, but you can continue from here. Since I don't know exactly what is the case and what it will be used against, I can't say what is the best choice - either create more properties for each column, or create a list of them with a key-value (may even be a separate class) bound to them - that way you can have it dynamically set for each column.

P.S. And still, if you know your widths from the start, or you have only 1 column that needs to be `Auto`, go with the traditional approach. Try not to overcomplicate everything and set your column definitions accordingly.

Edit: According to the updated question, we should take another approach. From the image I can't fully understand what the overall template is, but we have 2 options here:

1. To have all of the inputs to be the same width everywhere;
2. Or to have different widths.

However, whatever we choose, the column will have the same width for all views. What I can suggest in this case is to have all of the inputs be the same width as well (set their `HorizontalOptions` to `StartAndExpand` or `FillAndExpand`). And instead of setting their width explicitly, you can try to set the column's width to be (depending on your other columns' configuration):

1. If you don't have other columns set to `Star` (*) or you don't want the column to be proportionate to the other stars - set its width to `Star`. This way the column will take whatever it has remaining.
2. Or set the columns' width to be an `Absolute` value.

You shouldn't try to change the column dynamically - it won't be a good UX and you will also have to add checks when to stop.

To sum up, either set the third column (containing the entries) to `Star`, or to `Absolute`. If one of your other columns is set to `Auto` and the other has an `Absolute` width, you can easily set the third one to `Star`, which will take as much width as it has left). An `Absolute` should be used if you want to take "that much" of the width every time (use it with the largest entry/symbols that you want visible).

Comment: Hello Mihail, I will give you an example of what I am trying to do and add this to the question.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look into this problem I have.  If you have some minutes to spare, could you have a look at the code sample I attached to the question and suggest the changes for that code in your answer also.

Comment: "Unfortunately, this adds some overhead to the Grid's rendering and it is not small at any case." < Do you mean here that the Auto will slow down the grid rendering?

Comment: I will take a look at the updates in a while. In the meantime, if you have only 1 column that is set to `Auto`, you won't find any issues. The grid is designed that way to automatically fit it. In case of more columns set to `Auto`, then yes, the more columns that you have, the more computational time they will require for the grid to render. Most of the cases, you may not see it, but depending on your number of rows & cols and your data count, that may be obvious.

Comment: Thanks, I will review your suggestions and reply back here.